# how to add sphinx docs of imported libraries in python?

Tags: python, selenium, python-sphinx, autodoc

I have a python script "webaton.py" which imports selenium.

I have doc strings for my methods in my own class in the webaton.py and i set some of the methods of selenium as the method of my class using `setattr( )` method .

When I generate my documentation , im not getting the docstrings of the selenium's driver methods which I have setup as the functions of my own class using `setattr()`.

How do I include such external module's docstrings as docstrings of my class methods ? If not how to at least include the docs for the methods in selenium which I have used .

I have tried this , but it shows no documentation from the selenium library(Shows blank) . 
Also the docstrings i want are in the `selenium.webdriver.Chrome` class.

```
.. automodule:: webaton
    :members: Browser
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:


.. automodule:: selenium
   :members:
```

Comment: Are there any error messages?

Comment: No error messages, it just doesn't show the documentation of selenium

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].